# octomap Ubuntu dependencies

Tags: ros, octomap, release, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a full source build of ROS Kinetic w/ MoveIt and one of the "system" dependencies is the ROS-packaged libfcl-0.5-dev, which depends on ros-kinetic-octomap, which depends on ros-kinetic-catkin / python-catkin-pkg. I'm not super familiar with ROS packaging, so I have two questions:

1. Why does ros-kinetic-octomap depend on ros-kinetic-catkin? Looking at the [release repository](https://github.com/ros-gbp/octomap-release), it seems that somewhere between upstream and the final .deb a package.xml gets added with a run_depend on catkin. Why would catkin be needed at runtime?
2. Why is octomap even a ROS package (ie, with package.xml)? (as opposed to some other 3rd party libraries that are simply packaged and distributed)

I'm asking partly because this is installing a second catkin alongside my built-from-source version, but also to learn.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251415/octomap-ubuntu-dependencies/) by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-07**:
Interesting. I [posted a comment on the devel repo](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/commit/142bf4de6e423043d7e9b401372eae4edb2838a8#commitcomment-20397031) hoping the authors would respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 1. Why does ros-kinetic-octomap depend on ros-kinetic-catkin? Looking at the release repository, it seems that somewhere between upstream and the final .deb a package.xml gets added with a run_depend on catkin. Why would catkin be needed at runtime?

Got a [response from the author](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/commit/142bf4de6e423043d7e9b401372eae4edb2838a8#commitcomment-20399771) @AHornung; it's a way recommended in [REP136](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0136.html) for 3rd party release.

UPDATE 20170124; And the reason why REP-0136 requires `catkin` for 3rd party pkg is [this](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/87) (handling `setup.sh`).

> 2. Why is octomap even a ROS package (ie, with package.xml)? (as opposed to some other 3rd party libraries that are simply packaged and distributed)

I had the same question, then if you search within the OctoMap [code as of today](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/commit/45cbcafd9dc12953d00df78df65ec0594c557e3c), there's no ROS dependency there. So I assume it's just using ROS buildfarm as a release infrastructure so that the debian package name is `ros-kinetic-octomap`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0